# IDEA Community edition limit for maven-junit class tests

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have maven project in IDEA(Community version) within 7 classes. Add Junit tests for 5 classes, and when i try to add tests for another class IDEA gives me an error:

> "Failed to create class. Cannot Create Class 'ClinicTest'."

Is it a limit for junit-test classes in Community edition?

Comment: It is for sure not a limit for the community edition, restrictions on community editions doesn't involve anything related to your development, or coding

the restrictions will be for the features that you can have on the IDE, like support for Spring Boot, debugging, extensions, ...etc

Comment: Does your project build correctly on plain command line?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no any limit on IDEA. IDEA CE limitad only with plugin usage and another JetBrains features. You may reload your IDE, seems like an internal error.